# appengine jpql: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: __key__ filter value must be a Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpql

I'm using JPA on appengine 1.7.1 and I try to perform many specific querys by JPQL.
I found a problem when trying to filter an attribute of type Key (categoryKey) over some Item object

Item class

```
@Entity
public class Item extends Registro implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key = null;
    ....
    private Key categoryKey;
    ....
```

ItemDAO class

```
public List<Item> searchByCriteria(SearchItemForm form) {
   Query q = getEm().createQuery("Select i from " +
       Item.class.getName() + " i Where i.categoryKey = :CAT_KEY");
   q.setParameter("CAT_KEY", form.getCategoryKey());
   return q.getResultList();
}
```

I have been trying many ways but with no results.

I didnt foud any thead about this circumstances over appengine: JAVA, JPQL, the key attribute is not the ID on Item

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: How does `SearchItemForm` look, especially the return type of `getCategoryKey()`?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was a constant filter " where i.key is not null " I ommited in the cuestion. The "null" value was not detected as Key type.